# Windows 10 search in start menu sometimes doesn't work

Tags: windows-10

Here's a phenomenon I can't explain. I experienced it on my previous work computer at my previous job, and on my current work computer. Both of them are Windows 10 but different hardware.

Sometimes search in the start menu doesn't work. I mean, pressing "Start" in the keyboard and then immediately typing some text to search. Sometimes it lets me type and then shows results, sometimes it just closes the start menu immediately.

Any idea why? How do I make it always work? I know there are existing questions about this on SuperUser but these seem to be different cases, where it always doesn't work.